# Populating an Object with Information from a Child Object with Different Model (JS/Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Here is what I have. I created a project model that references a user model for an array of members.

```
var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {title: {
     type: String,
     required: true
    },

   members: [
       {user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
            }
       }],
});
```

User Schema (I have code that creates a model from both of these schemas)

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }

});
```

In a separate file, I want to export the JSON of a found project and include the information of the users in the members array, but I am not sure how to do that. This is the code I have right now.

```
const project = await Project.findById(req.params.proj_id).populate(
      'members'
    );
res.json(project);
```

It has no trouble finding the project but the only information I can get on the members is their id. I tried using for loops to gather the information from members separately using the id that I can get from the project, but the code gets messy and I am hoping to find a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose populate query to get all members associated with a project. It should populate array of objects users associated to a project. You should be doing something like this:

```
const project = await Project.findById(req.params.proj_id)
await project.populate('members').execPopulate()
console.log(project.members)
```

Mongoose docs for the reference: [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the model to your mongoose populate.

```
const project = await Project.findById(req.params.proj_id)
  .populate({
      'members',
       model: UserModel
    })
  .exec() 
res.json(project);
```

keep in mind you've to create UserModel just like
`const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);`